# Testing tools for Docker Images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A colleague of mine removed mysqli driver in one of our Dockerfile for PHP hosting and it causes problem. Luckily it is discovered in staging environment.

Is there any tools our there that does unit testing for docker images and if there are certain unavailability of an essential driver, fail it in the CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: I don't know of any tools but what I do in my projects, in CI/CD I run "docker exec commands" for the most important parts and analyse the output. I build the commands so that they return true or false and that makes it quick to fail the pipeline if something is missing. If you want to implement such a setup in the meantime and run into issues drop me a comment.

Comment: are you able to show me one simple example? i was thinking of running `php -m` and use some bash commands to double check

Comment: For example, if you run a container with mysql and you want to check that it uses version 5.7.24: docker run --rm database:1.0 sh -c 'test 1 -eq $(mysql --version | grep "5.7.24" | wc -l) && echo OK' Where database:1.0 is the image I am testing

Comment: Another example if I want to make sure that my image is using a certain kernel version: docker run --rm ubuntu-based:1.0 sh -c 'test 1 -eq $(uname -r | grep "4.9" | wc -l) && echo OK' The version can also be a parameter coming from environment or file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the latest shaded dist from https://github.com/dgroup/docker-unittests/releases:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/dgroup/docker-unittests/releases/download/s1.1.1/docker-unittests-app-1.1.1.jar
   ```
2. De fine an *.yml file with tests.

   ```
   version: 1.1

   setup:
   - apt-get update
   - apt-get install -y tree

   tests:

   - assume: java version is 1.9, Debian build
    cmd:    java -version
    output:
      contains:
       - openjdk version "9.0.1"
       - build 9.0.1+11-Debian

   - assume: curl version is 7.xxx
    cmd:    curl --version
    output:
      startsWith: curl 7.
      matches:
       - "^curl\\s7.*\\n.*\\nProtocols.+ftps.+https.+telnet.*\\n.*\\n$"
      contains:
       - AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API

   - assume:  Setup section installed `tree`
    cmd:     tree --version
    output:
      contains: ["Steve Baker", "Florian Sesser"]
   ```
3. Run tests for image

   ```
   java -jar docker-unittests.jar -f image-tests.yml -i openjdk:9.0.1-11
   ```

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSv72.png

More you can find in https://github.com/dgroup/docker-unittests.

Feel free to submit new issues/questions/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know about Google's tool for testing container images - [container-structure-test](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test)?

This utility can be easily integrated in CI/CD pipeline as artifact check step.